# instant image update wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there any plugin out there to update an image source based on user choices.

we have different choices :

flower color : {red,pink,white}

leaves color : {green,yellow}

I want an image of a flower based on user choices.

I have 6 images to show to the user based on his/her selections:
red flower with green leaves , red flower with yellow leaves , ...

or is there any alternative way to just update the leaves not entire image.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with a [WooCommerce variable product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/), which is a product type that is part of the base WooCommerce plugin. You'll need to have images of each possible flower color/leaf color combination. [Each combination will be a product variation and will have its own image](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/#add-variation-image). When a customer selects a certain combination (variation), that variation's image will be automatically shown.